# ICUDateTime: Getting Yesterday's Date?

Tags: date, icu

I'm trying to get the date of yesterday but I can't figure it out. Right now I'm using %ICUDateTime%yyyy-MM-dd% which comes out as 2014-01-05. How do I Display 2014-01-04 instead?

NOTE: I don't think this is tagged incorrectly, I saw that ICU also applies to c, c++, and java from the ICU website here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/intro

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I think your question pertains to the usage of Keyboard Maestro, http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/5/tokens.html and as such is probably best asked directly to them or to http://apple.stackexchange.com/  or superuser - suggest this be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Set the variable Previous day to this:

```
%ICUDateTimeMinus%1%Days%d%
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>Yesterday **was** 2014-01-04. At least where I live. Where do you live?</del> (Fixed the dates in the Question)

Why don't you use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)? Using Calendar, it would be like this:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String yesterday = format.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/)-solution is structurally very similar to JDK-stuff as @MartijnCourteaux had posted. Just use these classses instead:

- com.ibm.icu.util.GregorianCalendar
- com.ibm.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat

Structurally equivalent means the same look as in standard JDK (only the imports differ):

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String yesterday = format.format(c.getTime());
```

About the remark/question why not use JDK or JodaTime, I still see some arguments pro ICU4J, namely it has more internationalization power, for example more calendar implementations than JDK and JodaTime together. Anyway, it depends on you if you need the extra features of ICU4J or can be satisfied with standard JDK (in your shown example standard JDK would be enough).